# Connect MS SQL server with Filemaker Pro using ODBC

Tags: windows-server-2008, odbc, filemaker

I would like to connect to MS SQL server with running on Microsoft 2008 R2 Server to filemaker pro server 11 running on Mac server 10.6.8 using ODBC. HOw can i get to go about this? is there an easier way to do it apart from ODBC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, **ODBC** is is the only game in town. Currently there is no better way in the market that allows you to do it without ODBC, nevertheless the installation process can be complicated for non-programmers.

- [FileMaker 11 ODBC and JDBC Guide](http://www.filemaker.com/support/product/docs/fmp/fm11_odbc_jdbc_guide_en.pdf)